# How to quickly add and remove input language in windows?

Tags: keyboard

I have 2 keyboard layouts (English and Russian), which I normally use, but sometimes I need to type something in Czech. And I need to open settings-language and input-choose Czech language and then choose the QWERTY type of keyboard every time (because there is QWERTZ layout by default). And I hate when I leave Czech language and it pops up every time I want to switch to English. So is there a way to create a button which will quickly add an input language when I need to use and remove it when I don't need it anymore?

I've found something like that on Autohotkey forum [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70019-keyboard-layout-switcher-for-many-layouts/), but the script doesn't remove an input language completely, it just uses a certain shortcut to switch between chosen languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question, but this might help:

I developed for myself ahk (ahk v2) script for inputting czech characters by Win + 1-9 number combinations (correspoding keys on czech keyboard). You don't have to switch to czech layout if you just want to type a few czech characters...

```
#SC003::Send "ě"
+#SC003::Send "Ě"
#SC004::Send "š"
+#SC004::Send "Š"
#SC005::Send "č"
+#SC005::Send "Č"
#SC006::Send "ř"
+#SC006::Send "Ř"
#SC007::Send "ž"
+#SC007::Send "Ž"
#SC008::Send "ý"
+#SC008::Send "Ý"
#SC009::Send "á"
+#SC009::Send "Á"
#SC00A::Send "í"
+#SC00A::Send "Í"
#SC00b::Send "é"
+#SC00b::Send "É"
#SC01A::Send "ú"
+#SC01A::Send "Ú"
#SC027::Send "ů"
```

You get these SC key codes by putting

```
#InstallKeybdHook ;
```

in any of your ahk scripts. See https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys for explanation.

Due to the problems with encodings it is also probably necessary to save the script as UTF-8 with BOM.